# Unable to import module from another package

Tags: python-3.x, import, python-packaging

I have a directory structure like this

```
conf
    __init__.py
    settings.py
    abc.conf
    def.conf
src
    main.py
    xyz.py
```

src I chose not to make a package but a regular folder.
I am trying to import the settings.py file in the main.py and executing the whole thing with the command `python3 main.py`

My import statement in main.py : `import conf.settings`

The error I'm getting is `No module named conf.settings` and I can't get my head around it.

Is python failing to recognize conf as a package? Can packages contain files other than .py files (.conf files in my case)

Comment: It says
    ```from . import conf.settings
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

With the marker on ```config.settings```.Does it make a difference if I added the __init__.py file later? config was originally meant to be a folder, I later decided it was better suited as a package.

Comment: This new import statement says ```No module named conf``` and my __init__ file is empty. I'm running the ```python main.py``` command from inside the src folder.

Comment: Do you expect for Python to go into every single folder _upstream_ of your current working directory (which is `src` given that you're executing your program with `python3 main.py`), check them all for `__init__.py` and add them to its import module resolution path? That would take a lot of time on each run, not to mention all the possible conflict/path clashes it may cause. Therefore, your options are to either add your _parent_ folder to the Python path (`PYTHONPATH` env. variable), alter `sys.path` at runtime or, the simplest and most recommended approach - just move `conf` to `src`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When importing python search current directory and the `sys.path`. Since your `main.py` is in `src` folder it cannot see the `conf` package folder. Luckily you could update `sys.path` at runtime.

```
root
     conf
        __init__.py
        settings.py
     src
        main.py
```

So you could append `sys.path` from `main.py` before importing `conf` module. Try following:

```
# main.py
import os, sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), ".."))

from conf import settings
...
```

---

The other way is to update PYTHONPATH directly and add path to your script root directory.

Comment: Is this the recommended way of importing modules outside the current directory or is it just a hack of doing so?

Comment: It is legitimate way.

Comment: You could move your `conf` inside of `src` and avoid updating `sys.path` at all, if that is acceptable...